# Como testar se uma função já está definida no IAR ? (C)

Tags: c

Olá,

Estou fazendo uma biblioteca que deve ser facilmente portável a outros programas. Logo, tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
01 #ifndef delay_ms
02 #define delay_ms(X)              OSTimeDlyHMSM(0u, 0u, 0u, (X), OS_OPT_TIME_HMSM_STRICT, &err)
03 #endif
```

Porém, definida ou não a função 'delay_ms()' o código na linha 02 será definido. Existe um meio de realizar este teste?

Grato,

Comment: Você quer definir uma macro que “cubra” por uma função faltante, mas quer deixar a chamada à função nativa caso a função esteja disponível no ambiente de compilação?

Comment: A regra basica para macros é escreve-las em MAIUSCULAS. Isso evita redefinicoes de funcoes previamente declaradas ... `#define DELAY_MS(x) OSTimeDlyHMSM(...)`

Comment: @ctgPi exatamente. Dentro da minha biblioteca eu preciso de uma função de delay. Caso ela esteja definida eu a utilizo, se não a biblioteca usara a função OSTimeDly, que provém do sistema operacional utilizado.

Comment: O jeito certo de fazer isso é usar [`autotools`](https://autotools.io/index.html); o jeito porco é fazer um shell script que escreve um mini-programa `#include <…> int main() { delay_ms(1000); }` e tenta compilar (não precisa nem rodar) pra ver se dá erro (se der, insere a definição num `.h` que é construído dinâmicamente pré-compilação). Eu não sei fazer a primeira abordagem e não quero promover porqueira com a segunda; talvez alguém com experiência de `autotools` te dê uma força.